# ESLint rule to disallow specific string literal

Tags: eslint

I'd like to disallow the use of a specific string literal within my app to ensure devs are using an environment variable instead. I know how to disallow specific named variables and methods, but I'm not sure how I could do this with strings.

Comment: You'd probably have to do it via https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax